# Using a webview to play an mp3- is it possible to keep it playing even when the screen is locked?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, ios5.1

I have a portion of my app that simply launches a webview linked to an mp3 file- it opens the file and plays the audio. What I'd like to do is allow that audio to continue playing even if the user locks their iPhone. (As a side note, is there any way to replace the default Quicktime logo that appears in the player? Not that big a deal, just thought I'd ask =)

A third question- I also do the same thing (webview) with an .m3u linked file to stream live audio throughout the week- is it also possible to keep it playing when the iPhone is locked?

Thanks!!

Ben

Quick Edit: The same URLs work great in IOS Safari (locking and unlocking doesn't affect the audio. Just not in my app's webviews.

Comment: Do you have background mode or tasks ?

Comment: thanks for the reply! I don't believe so- all I have is the audio playing in a UIwebview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did find my answer though, in case anyone comes here looking. Easiest thing in the world too- just add a row to the plist file labeled "Required Background Modes" and under that set item 0's value to "App plays audio". Voila!

Answer (score 0):

Since the audio is in a UIWebView, I don't believe that you'd be able to play it in the background.
EDIT: I was wrong, adding "App Plays Audio" to the UIBackgroundModes will make it work even when audio is in a UIWebView.

Have you thought about just streaming the .mp3 file yourself?  Should be easy enough and you'd be able to setup background streaming.  To get you started, I'd check out Matt Gallagher's AudioStreamer class which easily allows you to stream .mp3 files and other audio files from the net: https://github.com/mattgallagher/AudioStreamer

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'll definitely look into it. I did find my answer though, in case anyone comes here looking. Easiest thing in the world too- just add a row to the plist file labeled "Required Background Modes" and under that set item 0's value to "App plays audio". Voila!

Comment: Ahh, didn't realize that it would work as well for UIWebView audio.  Cool, though :-)