# HTML5 audio not playing on UIWebView iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, html, audio, uiwebview

I am working on an iOS App in which i want to load a URL on UIWebView, which is HTML page having number of buttons e.g Video, audio, link etc. When i click on video or link its working fine but not playing audio, but working fine on browser .
This is the link.

http://dotwapp.com/live-media-ar-latest-new/pages/template_new/select_templete.php?app_id=5&target_file=530897219_1446543407_1114783040.png&p_id=&video=&audio=1693670338_1446543407_832353985.mp4&image=1872962265_1446543407_518980357.png&bg_image=&link=http://w3schools.com&v_link=

any help will be appreciated .

Comment: Have you check on your Mac book with safari ? is it working ?

Comment: I checked on my MAC book, it is not playing audio file in safari. Check the code of select_templete.php file. No issue from iOS app

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12310922/using-a-webview-to-play-an-mp3-is-it-possible-to-keep-it-playing-even-when-the

Comment: just add a row to the plist file labeled "Required Background Modes" and under that set item 0's value to "App plays audio"

Comment: Did you check if there is an error in web view delegate `- webView:didFailLoadWithError:` ?

Answer (score 7):

Apple has blocked any HTML5 auto play for awhile on mobile iOS which we all know. The official reason is that they felt it would be a drain on the mobile carriers bandwidth if everyone could stream audio and video from web pages.

There is a way to override the autoplay ban but you need to adjust your Xcode file in order to do that.

You just need to add the line in your view controller.m file

self.Webview.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = NO;

Comment: but its playing my video file . .  @Selva M

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing this property out! This helped me a lot :-)

Apparently this is deprecated since SDK 10+, we should now use `mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback`.

See it here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebviewconfiguration/1851524-mediatypesrequiringuseractionfor

Answer (score 0):

May be you have **muted your device sound?**. Check the left side switch on your iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

```
func newWebView() {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
                webConfiguration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
                if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                    webConfiguration.mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback = []
                } else {
                    webConfiguration.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = false
                }
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        browserURL.delegate = self
```